# Android loss of accelerometer data

Tags: android, service, accelerometer, sensors, sensormanager

My problem is the following:
I'm developing an application that simply store accelerometer samples in an array and then analyzes these data to find a walk pattern. I've written the following service :

```
public class gService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer;
    private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";
    private StepAnalyzer analyzer;
    private int numPass;

    public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Check action just to be on the safe side.
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                //Log.v("shake mediator screen off","trying re-registration");
                // Unregisters the listener and registers it again.
                senSensorManager.unregisterListener(gService.this);
                senSensorManager.registerListener(gService.this, senAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        analyzer = new StepAnalyzer(getApplicationContext());
        numPass = 1;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent){
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];
            float gNorm = ((float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z))/ SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY ;
            long time = sensorEvent.timestamp / 1000000;
            ......
            // other operations

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }


}
```

The problem is that when the screen is on, the accelerometer provides samples at the right frequency( 20ms -> SENSOR_DELAY_GAME ) instead, when the screen is off, the accelerometer samples are given in a "random" way, with intervals of 20ms and intervals up to 20s. 
As you can see in the code, i've already implemented the workaround seen in related questions: catch the screen off event and unregister and re-register the listener, but without any luck.

I'va also seen that this behaviour could be related to my device, I've a Motorola Moto X 2014 edition.

To explain this beheaviour, I attach the plot of the timestamp differences bewtween two consecutive sensor events.
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZvvV.png)

On X-axis -> the # of sample
On Y-axis -> the time between 2 consecutivesamples in ms

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apparently this is quite common behaviour and I've seen it myself as well. There are also [older discussions about the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+accelerometer+screen+off). Depending on your app. keeping the display on with a [wake lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) may be an option.

Comment: Yes it can be an option, but i'm looking for a better solution, if possible. This is my last choice. Thanks for the answer